# How to get user certificate from active directory using ldap from JAVA?

Tags: java, ldap, x509certificate

```
//Code For Generate Certificate

byte[] userCERT = (byte[])attrs.get("userCertificate").get(); 
ByteArrayInputStream bais = new ByteArrayInputStream( (userCERT)) ;
CertificateFactory cf = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");
X509Certificate cert = (X509Certificate)cf.generateCertificate(bais);
```

> Code i have attached above

Comment: what is the issue that you are facing?

Comment: java.lang.NullPointerException
 at com.LDAPExample.RetrieveUserAttributes.getUserBasicAttributes(RetrieveUserAttributes.java:92)
 at com.LDAPExample.RetrieveUserAttributes.main(RetrieveUserAttributes.java:25)

Comment: what is the code in line `RetrieveUserAttrib‌​utes.java:92`

Comment: Lin No 92: X509Certificate cert = (X509Certificate)cf.generateCertificate(bais);

Comment: and on 25 i am calling custome method which return whole information of user.